# Несколько предложений на пунктуацию

Tags: пунктуация

1) *Расскажи* (,) -- *какова бы ни была причина* (,) -- *кто тебя обидел?*

В каком месте нужна запятая, да и нужна ли вообще? Важно знать, какая пунктуация правильна именно в данном синтаксисе, изменять ничего не нужно.

2) *Что нужно обществу от книг* **(?)**  *определяется самой культурой.*

Какой знак лучше всего поставить вместо знака вопроса? Я бы поставил тире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Расскажи ― какова бы ни была причина, ― кто тебя обидел?**

[Розенталь. § 26. Вводные и вставные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123)
  Перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура второй части основного предложения или вставной конструкции:

Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит, — он пытается стать рационалистом — вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции;

Это вариант с **перенесенной** запятой. Иногда в подобных случаях используется **симметричная** постановка запятых: **Расскажи, ― какова бы ни была причина, ― кто тебя обидел?**

2) ЧтО нужно обществу от книг ― определяется самой культурой.

Да, здесь ставится тире, **изъяснительное придаточное в препозиции**. Постановке тире способствует и интонация, так как логическое ударение падает на первое слово.

Comment: Всегда с удовольствием читаю Ваши ответы! Спасибо! Можно еще один вопрос здесь (просто не хочется новую тему создавать ради него)? Нужна ли здесь запятая? Я сам не врач и (,) медицина мне совсем не интересна. Это ССП же, верно?

Comment: Спасибо и Вам. Запятая в вашем предложении нужна, это ССП, как Вы правильно заметили, общих элементов нет.

Comment: А можно еще один глупый, но очень любопытный вопрос? :)?
Вы обратились ко мне сначала на "Вы", то есть с большой буквы, собственно, как и полагается, но при этом здесь "Запятая в вашем предложении нужна..." вашем написали с маленькой буквы. Так и должно быть?

Comment: По поводу выбора прописной или строчной буквы  в местоимениях Вы, Ваш существуют разные мнения. Например, некоторые считают, что "вы", а не "ты" - это уже достаточно вежливо, а "Вы" - это официальное обращение.  Здесь на форуме тоже по-разному пишут: то  вы, то   Вы. Но "в вашем предложении" я написала строчную букву машинально или интуитивно, всё-таки оно не совсем ваше. Как-то странно выглядела бы здесь прописная буква.

Comment: а я лично понимаю так, что обращение "Вы" с прописной буквы адресовано одной личности, например при диалоге, а если обращение ко множественному числу, то соответственно "вы" со строчной. Только вот непонятно, всегда ли с прописной писать, если обращение к одному человеку...

Comment: Обращение к группе лиц - это однозначно "вы", но сейчас речь идет о записях в Сети. Люди на форумах лично не знакомы, но  бывает, что общаются чуть ли не каждый день. В этом случае "Вы" (при обращении к одному человеку) иногда кажется слишком  официальной формой.

Comment: @PersonaNonGrata  Извините, поправка. "Нужна ли здесь запятая? Я сам не врач и (,) медицина мне совсем не интересна". Правильно будет: "Я сам не врач, и медицина мне совсем не интересна".

Comment: Да, всё верно, скобку нужно было поставить перед союзом И.

Comment: это я поспешил уже))

Answer (score 0):

Фраза стилистически неудачна. Из=за этого проблемы в пунктуационном оформлении.
Если задача "рассказать", то при чем тут причина?  "причина рассказать"? 
А если "причина обидеть", то кажущееся естественным оформление (предлагаемое, в частности Sibуlla) вставной конструкции с помощью тире неудачно, поскольку зрительно нарушается смысловая связь "обиды" и её причины.

В первом случае я бы предпочел оформление с помощью запятых: *"Расскажи, какова бы ни была причина, кто тебя обидел"*.
Во втором лучше перенести вcтавную конcтрукцию в конец. *"Расскажи, какова бы ни была причина, кто тебя обидел"*.